# Need to add space between SubPlots for X axis label, maybe remove labelling of axis notches

Tags: python, matplotlib

Looking to add in vertical space between plotted graphs to allow a X-Axis label to show:

Each graph needs to have space to show the day, currently the last 2 graphs are the only one's that show simply because the graphs are overlapping it.

Also curious if I could actually remove the notch labels for the X-Axis for the graphs above the one's marked Thursday/Friday, i.e. the bottom X-axis is the only one that shows. Same for the Y-Axis, but only the graphs on the left having the scale shown.

*Unfortunately I can't post an image to show this since I don't have enough rep.

Code snippet:

```
import mathlib.pyplot as pyplot
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,1)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,2, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,3, sharex=ax2, sharey=ax2)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,4, sharex=ax3, sharey=ax3)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,5, sharex=ax4, sharey=ax4)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,6, sharex=ax5, sharey=ax5)
ax7 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,7, sharex=ax6, sharey=ax6)
ax1.plot(no_dict["Saturday"],'k.-',label='Saturday')
ax1.set_xlabel('Saturday')
ax1.axis([0,24,0,10000])
pyplot.suptitle('Title')
pyplot.xlabel('Hour in 24 Hour Format')
ax2.plot(no_dict["Sunday"],'b.-',label='Sunday')
ax2.set_xlabel('Sunday')
...
```

[image: too crowded]

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use [subplots_adjust](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust).  In your case this looks good:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
```

to remove the tick labels do this:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
```

Similar for the `yticklabels`.  However, you cannot share the x-axis with the plots that do have tick labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the spacing around a certain subplot, instead of all of them, you can adjust the position of the axes of that subplot using:

```
bbox=plt.gca().get_position()
offset=-.03
plt.gca().set_position([bbox.x0, bbox.y0 + offset, bbox.x1-bbox.x0, bbox.y1 - bbox.y0])
```

If `offset < 0`, the subplot is moved down. If `offset > 0`, the subplot is moved up.

Note that the subplot will disappear if offset is so big that the new position of the subplot overlaps with another subplot.