# subplots are overlapping axis labels

Tags: python, layout, plot, matplotlib

I have created a figure in python which contains multiple subplots. I have also added various axis labels to some of the axes on the figures. For examples:

```
plt.xlabel('Phase ($^\circ$)',fontsize=10)
```

I notice though, that when the final figure is produced, the other subplots are allowed to overlap and obscure the words of the axis labels.

Is there a way that I can stop this happening?

Comment: Have you seen the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159065/need-to-add-space-between-subplots-for-x-axis-label-maybe-remove-labelling-of-a)? Perhaps that may help.

Answer (score 23):

just add the following:

```py
plt.tight_layout()
```

I hope it helps. [Link to documentation.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)