# using sharex with odd number of subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have an odd number of subplots like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.plot(range(10))
fig.delaxes(axes.flat[-1])
```

I want them all to have the same x-axis, but easily add the x-ticks back to the plot on the right, since there is no longer a 4th plot.

It seems like there should be an easier/cleaner solution than adding each subplot manually (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167516/matplotlib-pyplot-shared-axis-for-odd-number-of-subplots)), but I can't seem to find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [setp](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.setp.html#matplotlib.artist.setp) to make the xtick labels visible for `ax[0][1]` like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.plot(range(10))
# for matploltib version 2.0.1
plt.setp(axes[0][1].get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
# for matplotlib version 2.1.1
axes[0][1].xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=True, labeltop=False)
fig.delaxes(axes.flat[-1])
plt.show()
```

which will result in

[image]

Comment: what version of matplotlib are you using? I tried this with 2.1.0 and 2.1.1 (from conda-forge) and couldn't get this result (`axes[0][1]` still has no tick labels).

Comment: see my latest edit. If the answer helped, please upvote/accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: That worked, thanks! I upvoted the answer, but don't have enough reputation for it to show up :)