# Matpltlib/Seaborn remove empty axis and also move shared-x tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I'm plotting a selection of graphs using matplotlib and seaborn. When I remove the empty axes, the tick labels do not move to the graphs above them - is there a way to do this?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(9,4,figsize=(20, 30), sharey=True, sharex=True)
for r in range(0,9):
   for c in range(0,4):
    
       if (r==8) and (c>=2):
           pass
       else:
           data_red = preds[preds['region']==regions[(r*4)+c]]
           sns.scatterplot(data=data_red, x='y_test', y='preds', ax=ax[r,c], alpha=0.6, legend=False)
           ax[r,c].plot(sl,sl, 'r-')
           ax[r,c].set_xlabel('')
           ax[r,c].set_ylabel('')
           ax[r,c].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
           ax[r,c].annotate(regions[(r*4)+c], (550,200), fontsize=15)
           ax[r,c].annotate(f'RMSE: {rmse_regs[(r*4)+c]}', (550,150), fontsize=15)
           ax[r,c].annotate(f'Bias: {bias_regs[(r*4)+c]}', (550,100), fontsize=15)      
        
        
        
fig.delaxes(ax[8,2])
fig.delaxes(ax[8,3])
fig.text(0.5, -0.02, 'x', fontsize=25, ha='center')
fig.text(-0.02, 0.5, 'y', fontsize=25, va='center', rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of what's happening here]

[image: What I want to happen]

Comment: Could you add an example of what you expect to happen? E.g. two pictures, can be hand / powerpoint / your favourite illustrator drawn of what you want to happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no data presented, I created a graph using the [data set](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) in seaborn. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800922/using-sharex-with-odd-number-of-subplots-in-matplotlib) as a reference for how to add the x-axis tick marks due to the deletion of the graph.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(9,4,figsize=(10, 15), sharey=True, sharex=True)

for ax in axs.ravel():
    sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", ax=ax, alpha=0.6, legend=False)
    ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
    ax.plot(np.arange(tips['total_bill'].min(),tips['total_bill'].max(),10),
            np.arange(tips['tip'].min(),tips['tip'].max(),2),'r--')

fig.delaxes(axs[8,2])
fig.delaxes(axs[8,3])
# add xticks
axs[7,2].xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=True, labeltop=False)
axs[7,3].xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=True, labeltop=False)

fig.text(0.5, -0.02, 'x', fontsize=25, ha='center')
fig.text(-0.02, 0.5, 'y', fontsize=25, va='center', rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]